# How can I list the extra features of a Python package

Tags: python, pip, package

Some Python packages have extra features that can be installed by putting them into brackets such as the *security* extra for the [requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/community/updates/#id54) package:

```sh
pip install requests[security]
```

Is there a way to list all the extras of a given package ?

I cannot find anything like that in the pip documentation.

Comment: There is now straight forward way that I know of, and it is indeed something that would be nice to have.

Answer (score 7):

There are two open feature requests in pip about this:

- [#3797 - pip show doesn't handle extras_requires](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3797)
- [#4824 - Add support for outputting a list of extras and their requirements.](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4824)

In the meantime, a workaround using [importlib_metadata](https://pypi.org/project/importlib_metadata)'s API and working for already installed packages has been provided by jaraco.

Copy-pasting it below:

> An even better alternative would be to use importlib_metadata, which has an API.
>
> ```py
> >>> import importlib_metadata
> >>> importlib_metadata.metadata('xonsh').get_all('Provides-Extra')
> ['linux', 'mac', 'proctitle', 'ptk', 'pygments', 'win']
> >>> importlib_metadata.metadata('xonsh').get_all('Requires-Dist')
> ["distro; extra == 'linux'", "gnureadline; extra == 'mac'", "setproctitle; extra == 'proctitle'", "prompt-toolkit; extra == 'ptk'", "pygments (>=2.2); extra == 'pygments'", "win-unicode-console; extra == 'win'"]
> ```
>
> And use packaging to parse them:
>
> ```py
> >>> req = next(map(packaging.requirements.Requirement, importlib_metadata('xonsh').get_all('Requires-Dist')))
> >>> req.name
> 'distro'
> >>> req.specifier
> <SpecifierSet('')>
> >>> req.extras
> set()
> >>> req.marker
> <Marker('extra == "linux"')>
> ```