# How can we find all extra dependencies for PySpark when deploying via pip?

Tags: pyspark, pip, pypi

I am trying to deploy PySpark locally using the instructions at

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/getting_started/install.html#using-pypi

I can see that extra dependencies are available, such as sql and pandas_on_spark that can be deployed with

`pip install pyspark[sql,pandas_on_spark]`

But how can we find all available extras?

Looking in the json of the pyspark package (based on https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyPIJSON)

https://pypi.org/pypi/pyspark/json

I could not find the possible extra dependencies (as described in [What is 'extra' in pypi dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52474931/what-is-extra-in-pypi-dependency)); the value for requires_dist is null.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: As far as I know, you can not easily. If it is not documented, then you will have to look at the code/config for the packaging. In this case, here: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/eb30a27e53158e64fffaa6d32ff9369ffbae0384/python/setup.py#L262-L274 -- `ml`, `mllib`, `sql`, `pandas_on_spark`.

Comment: If you already installed pyspark, you can use a workaround described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63603540/6942134) to list its extras.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you can not easily get the list of *extras*. If this list is not clearly documented, then you will have to look at the code/config for the packaging. In this case, [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/eb30a27e53158e64fffaa6d32ff9369ffbae0384/python/setup.py#L262-L274) which gives the following list: `ml`, `mllib`, `sql`, and `pandas_on_spark`.

Comment: thank you, all these four extras are understood by pip install

Comment: As of 2023-08-07, there is an additional extra `connect` for Spark Connect.